# How to efficiently calculate the autocorrelation function of multidimensional data?

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization, correlation

I have a very large dataset of the shape (T, N) and I would like to calculate the autocorrelation function in Python like in [numpy.correlate](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.correlate.html):

```
c[k] = sum_n sum_t a[t, n] * a[t+k, n]
```

but summing over all samples N and without (!) using a for-loop. A calculation according to the 'valid' mode would be sufficient. However, this function only allows for 1-dimensional arrays. Is there a fast way to do this?

Comment: How about [scipy.signal.correlate2d](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.signal.correlate2d.html)?

Comment: Unfortunately, that function calculates all cross correlations, also between different samples. However, I would like to calculate the correlation only in T-direction while summing over the N-direction.

Comment: How about correlate1d and apply along each row : https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.filters.correlate1d.html?

Comment: Hmm, possible, but still a for loop :/

Answer (score 0):

I realized, this has been asked [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4503325/autocorrelation-of-a-multidimensional-array-in-numpy). Performing a Fourier transform and then calculating the power spectrum can do the trick!